# difference between create constraint non clustered and create index non clustered

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

I am new to sql server. i was trying to learn creating index. i tried to create a table with below query:

```
CREATE TABLE [Ref].[Country](
    [CountryId] [uniqueidentifier]  NOT NULL,
    [CountryName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime2](2) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [UCI_CountryName] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([CountryName] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY ([CountryId])
)
```

The non clustered index got created automatically on primary key. Now, i want to create NCI on Primary key column with INCLUDE. I did create it with below query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_CountryId] ON [Ref].[Country]
(
    [CountryId] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([CountryName])
```

As you can see in below image, there is two NCI on same column that is CountryId, one is created by default while creating a table(PK_Country) and another which i created with INCLUDE using above query(NCI_CountryId).

I do not want two NCI's on same column, need only NCI created with INCLUDE. Is there a way to create NCI with include on PK at time of creating table ?

I'm working on sql server on Azure VM.

[image]

Comment: Please read this link for more understanding --> https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-indexes/sql-server-clustered-indexes/

Answer (score 2):

With this:

```
CREATE TABLE [Ref].[Country](
    [CountryId] [uniqueidentifier]  NOT NULL,
    [CountryName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](2) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime2](2) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [UCI_CountryName] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([CountryName] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY ([CountryId])
)
```

> i want to create NCI on Primary key column with INCLUDE.

You already have it.  A non-clustered index always contains the "row locator", which for a table with a clustered index is the clustered index key.  The leaf level of the non-clustered PK with have (CountryId,CountryName) rows, but sorted by CountryId, whereas in the clustered index the rows are sorted by CountryName.

For a unique index the clustered index columns are stored as "included columns" only on the leaf level.  For a non-unique index the clustered index columns are added as trailing index keys.

But you cannot include additional columns in a Primary Key constraint.  You can implement the identical physical design by adding a unique, non-clustered index with included columns.

Also there's nothing wrong with using a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER for the clustered index key, so long as your table isn't large, or you generate the value with [NEWSEQUENTIALID().](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: For details read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-index-design-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: CREATE TABLE [Ref].[User](

 [UserRegisteredId] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,

 [UserName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,

 [FirstName] [varchar](500) NULL,

 [LastName] [varchar](500) NULL,

 [PhoneNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,

 [Email] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [UCI_UserName] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([UserName] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY ([UserRegisteredId])
)
How to create NCI on PK with INCLUDE(FirstName, LastName) while creating table ?

Comment: See update to answer.

Comment: do you mean CountryName is already included in NCI creted on PK CountryId ? i don't need to create another NCI on PK CountryId with INCLUDE(CountryName) ? correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes.  The clustered index key columns are always included.